# Iterative range function in Scheme/Lisp

Tags: scheme, range, lisp, racket

I wanted to implement range function (start, end, inc), that generates all natural numbers from start to end, with increment of inc.
This is first version:

```
(define (gen start end step)
  (if (>= start end)
  '()
  (cons start (gen (+ step start) end step))))
```

The problem is, this is not tail-recursive. Another try:

```
(define (gen-iter start end step acc)
  (if (>= start end)
    acc
    (gen-iter (+ step start) end step (cons start acc))))
```

But this generates a list in reverse order :)
So yeah, I can reverse it with O(n), and be happy, but I kind of stuck here, trying to make function that will construct a list with proper order from start to end, **without appending on each iteration**, as append is costly.
There is also a list built-in, but I don't know how it operates.

Comment: You could use a queue: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Queue/Usage#Racket

Comment: The canonical Scheme way is to use `reverse` and I dare say this is not going to be the bottleneck of your application anyway. As for how Racket does it, use "open defining file" in Dr Racket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As uselpa already said in a comment, the solution would be to use `reverse` at the end. After expansion, the racket implementation of `range` is pretty similar to `reverse`ing the result of your `gen-iter` function, except for some cases you probably weren't thinking about.

The actual implementation of `range` in racket uses `(for/list ([i (in-range start end step)]) i)`, but what *that* expands to is actually equivalent to

```
(reverse
 (for/fold ([fold-var null])
           ([i (in-range start end step)])
   (cons i fold-var)))
```

Except that it uses an `alt-reverse` function instead of `reverse`, and it uses `for/fold/derived` for better error reporting. And if you expand that, it is equivalent to this after some simplification (deleting unnecessary `let-values` wrappers, error-checking, etc.)

```
(reverse
 (let ([start start] [end end] [inc step])
   (let for-loop ([fold-var null] [pos start])
     (if (if (>= step 0)
             (< pos end)
             (> pos end))
         (let ([i pos])
           (let ([fold-var (cons i fold-var)])
             (for-loop
              fold-var
              (+ pos inc))))
         fold-var))))
```

The named let there is equivalent to defining a helper function like this: (after substituting some `let`s and lifting the helper outside the `range` function)

```
(define (range start end step)
  (reverse
   (range-reversed null start end step)))
(define (range-reversed fold-var pos end step)
  (if (if (>= step 0)
          (< pos end)
          (> pos end))
      (range-reversed
       (cons pos fold-var)
       (+ pos step)
       end
       step)
      fold-var))
```

This is still different from your solution because your solution assumes that `step` is positive, while this one works even when `step` is negative. If `step` is positive, the if condition will be `(< pos end)` instead of the nested if.

It also uses `(< pos end)` where you used `(>= pos end)`, but it also switches the if cases. That's equivalent to your solution if `(< x y)` is the same as `(not (>= x y))`, because `(if (not a) b c)` is equivalent to `(if a c b)`. However, there's at least one case I can think of where that wouldn't be true, where either `start` or `end` is `+nan.0`. For that case, racket's `range` function would return an empty list, while your solution would go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

It's not always so easy to see it but "reverse" is a keyword here. To make it iterative you need to do the actual job in reverse:

```
(define (my-range start end step)      
  (define (helper n acc)
    (if (= end n)
        (cons n acc)
        (helper (- n step) (cons n acc))))

  (define actual-end end) ; this needs improvement
  (helper actual-end '()))
```

Just as `range` in racket you should get these results:

```
(my-range 1 10 1)  ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
(my-range 10 1 -1) ; ==> (10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2)
```

To get this correct `actual-end` needs to do find the correct value based on math.

```
(my-range 1 10 2)  ; ==> (1 3 5 7 9)  (actual-end should be 9)
(my-range 10 1 -2) ; ==> (10 8 6 4 2) (actual-end should be 2)
```

I guess you can use the `ceiling` procedure along with the normal math procedures to get this correct.